# Datetime format update for a range of columns in pandas

Tags: pandas, datetime

I have a pandas dataframe with a subset of 30+ columns with values per month, named like "2018-09-01 00:00:00", which I want to reformat to a Month-Year like "Sep 2018".

I found [this useful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47164814/converting-timestamp-into-month-name-and-year-as-a-data-frame-column-name):

```
df.iloc[:, 13:].rename(columns='{:%b %Y}'.format)
```

but applying it to whole df ruins data in these columns:

```
df.iloc[:, 13:] = df.iloc[:, 13:].rename(columns='{:%b %Y}'.format)
```

How do I change format in a range of columns, that I know by index?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `rename`:

```
old_col_names = df.filter(regex=r'\d{4}-\d{2}').columns.tolist()
new_col_names = pd.to_datetime(old_col_names).strftime('%b %Y')
df = df.rename(columns=dict(zip(old_col_names, new_col_names)))
```

Output:

```
# Before rename
>>> df
   id  2018-09-01 00:00:00  2018-10-01 00:00:00  data
0   0                    1                    2     3

# After rename
>>> df
   id  Sep 2018  Oct 2018  data
0   0         1         2     3
```

Setup:

```
data = {'id': [0], '2018-09-01 00:00:00': [1],
        '2018-10-01 00:00:00': [2], 'data': [3]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Comment: I wonder how to transform that to datetime-index? Now column names seem to be stored as strings, not allowing to slice them as dates